# How to name and create files in a loop

Tags: c

I found a code but it's giving error:

> 'fopen_s' not declared in this scope.

Here it is:

```
main (){
    FILE *ptr;
    char name[20];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        _snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%d.txt", i);
        fopen_s(&ptr, name, "w");

        //operations to fill data into file i.txt;
        fclose(ptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to use functions declared in `stdio.h`?

Comment: Are you on Windows and using Microsoft compilers.  Although `fopen_s()` is part of C11, it is defined as optional in Annex K.  It is only implemented by Microsoft. Your use of `_snprint()` indicates a Windows environment; everywhere else, the function is `snprintf()` without the leading underscore. Including the correct header is part of the battle; probably even most of the battle.  But if you’re not on Windows, your problems have barely begun.

Comment: i am using windows Dev C++ Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Always `#include` headers that you're going to use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

And remember the return type of `main()` is **`int`**:

```
int main (){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include stdlib.h aswell